# Code Editor (ace editor)(text/JavaScript/sh/sh etc editors) in angular 8

Tags: shell, yaml, editor, angular8, text-editor

How to Integrate editor code editor in angular8 application

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-ace-editor

Answer (score -2):

**ng2-ace-edi[image]tor** module is you can use for angular8 also

Refer the link for full code  angular6 version  https://stackblitz.com/edit/ace-code-editor

For **angular8** need to add below script in **app.component.ts** file

import 'brace/index';

import 'brace/theme/monokai';

import 'brace/mode/html';

import 'brace/mode/javascript';